# How to Avoid auto-snap Crooked Arrows in PowerPoint

Tags: layout, drawing, powerpoint

I have a row of boxes in powerpoint that are all exactly aligned and all exactly the same size.  I connect them with arrows (the kind that can have corners in the middle and all the segments are exactly horizontal or vertical).  The arrows are "snapped" into the snap sites on the center of the left and right sides of the boxes.  Like this:

[image]

Annoyingly, the tip of the arrow seems to hook in just an annoying smidgen below where the tail hooks in.  Sometimes the tip is higher than the tail.  But for whatever reason they don't just make a straight line.  This make every single arrow have an annoying bend right in the middle of it.  This is driving me crazy.

It seems I can use a straight arrow, but I just always draw the diagram with the same arrow because I will move the boxes around I don't want to have to be changing arrow types all the time.

Is there ANY WAY to get this line to just be straight when the snap points are lined up?

Comment: I've seen this happen before; sometimes it's just a display anomaly; zooming in or out makes the jaggies in the lines go away. If they appear in slide show view or when printed, it's a more serious matter.

Comment: Not a display anomaly.  It is absolutely there, at every magnification scale, and in presentation mode.  If I open object properties, it shows a height of 0.01 inches.  If I manually set the height to zero, it _disconnects_ the arrow from the endpoint so it no longer moves with the box.

Comment: So much for the *easy* answers.  Strictly speaking, this discussion belongs in SuperUser rather than StackOverflow, since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with writing code to control PPT. I'd suggest posting it there and if possible, post a link to a sample file on Dropbox or the like. Also indicate exactly which platform, OS version/bitness and Office version/bitness you have.  Include in the PPT file a screenshot of the File | Account screen (for recent Windows versions) or the equivalent for Mac versions.